# Awaitable AutoResetEvent

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

What would be the async (awaitable) equivalent of AutoResetEvent?

If in the classic thread synchronization we would use something like this:

```
    AutoResetEvent signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    void Thread1Proc()
    {
        //do some stuff
        //..
        //..

        signal.WaitOne(); //wait for an outer thread to signal we are good to continue

        //do some more stuff
        //..
        //..
    }

    void Thread2Proc()
    {
        //do some stuff
        //..
        //..

        signal.Set(); //signal the other thread it's good to go

        //do some more stuff
        //..
        //..
    }
```

I was hoping that in the new async way of doing things, something like this would come to be:

```
SomeAsyncAutoResetEvent asyncSignal = new SomeAsyncAutoResetEvent();

async void Task1Proc()
{
    //do some stuff
    //..
    //..

    await asyncSignal.WaitOne(); //wait for an outer thread to signal we are good to continue

    //do some more stuff
    //..
    //..
}

async void Task2Proc()
{
    //do some stuff
    //..
    //..

    asyncSignal.Set(); //signal the other thread it's good to go

    //do some more stuff
    //..
    //..
}
```

I've seen other custom made solutions, but what I've managed to get my hands on, at some point in time, still involves locking a thread. I don't want this just for the sake of using the new await syntax. I'm looking for a true awaitable signaling mechanism which does not lock any thread.

Is it something I'm missing in the Task Parallel Library?

EDIT: Just to make clear: SomeAsyncAutoResetEvent is an entirely made up class name used as a placeholder in my example.

Comment: For one-time-use, a `TaskCompletionSource` whose result is ignored by the awaiting task.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/AArnott/1084951 maybe?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I see it uses a lock, which will block a thread from the thread pool. I was hoping for something not involving a blocked thread.

Comment: A lock doesn't necessarily mean a thread is blocked.

Comment: @DarkFalcon True. And in this case it might even not block any thread.

Comment: @MatthewWatson This extension method uses ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject which "Registers a delegate that is waiting for a WaitHandle.". I understand from this bit that a thread from the pool will block on that waithandle. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to build your own, [Stephen Toub has the definitive blog post on the subject](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-2-asyncautoresetevent).

If you want to use one that's already written, [I have one in my AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncAutoResetEvent). AFAIK, there's no other option as of the time of this writing.

Comment: Why wouldn't a `new SemaphoreSlim(1)` work, `WaitOne()` is `WaitAsync()` and `Set()` becomes `Release()`

Comment: AREs and Semaphores are very similar (though usually used differently). The semantic difference comes in if the primitive is signalled when it is already set.

Comment: anything wrong with `await Task.Run(() => loginWaiter.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(75)));`

Comment: @AshleyJackson: That approach does use another thread. Some synchronization primitives do not allow this (e.g., `Mutex`, `Monitor`), but since this is an `AutoResetEvent`, it should work.

Comment: I think those who are named "Stephen" are born for asynchronous anything.

Comment: Stephen Toubs post seems to have been moved [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-2-asyncautoresetevent/)

Answer (score 23):

Here's [the source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/11/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-2-asyncautoresetevent/) for Stephen Toub's `AsyncAutoResetEvent`, in case his blog goes offline.

```cs
internal sealed class AsyncAutoResetEvent
{
    private static readonly Task s_completed = Task.FromResult(true);
    private readonly Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> _waits = new Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();
    private bool _signaled;

    public Task WaitAsync()
    {
        lock (_waits)
        {
            if (_signaled)
            {
                _signaled = false;
                return s_completed;
            }
            else
            {
                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                _waits.Enqueue(tcs);
                return tcs.Task;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Set()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<bool>? toRelease = null;

        lock (_waits)
        {
            if (_waits.Count > 0)
            {
                toRelease = _waits.Dequeue();
            }
            else if (!_signaled)
            {
                _signaled = true;
            }
        }

        toRelease?.SetResult(true);
    }
}
```

Here's a slightly extended version that uses newer C#/.NET APIs and supports cancellation of the wait:

```cs
internal sealed class AsyncAutoResetEvent(bool signaled)
{
    private readonly Queue<TaskCompletionSource> _queue = new();

    private bool _signaled = signaled;

    public Task WaitAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        lock (_queue)
        {
            if (_signaled)
            {
                _signaled = false;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            else
            {
                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
                if (cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled)
                {
                    // If the token is cancelled, cancel the waiter.
                    var registration = cancellationToken.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled(), useSynchronizationContext: false);

                    // If the waiter completes or faults, unregister our interest in cancellation.
                    tcs.Task.ContinueWith(
                        _ => registration.Unregister(),
                        cancellationToken,
                        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion | TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted,
                        TaskScheduler.Default);
                }
                _queue.Enqueue(tcs);
                return tcs.Task;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Set()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource? toRelease = null;

        lock (_queue)
        {
            if (_queue.Count > 0)
            {
                toRelease = _queue.Dequeue();
            }
            else if (!_signaled)
            {
                _signaled = true;
            }
        }

        // It's possible that the TCS has already been cancelled.
        toRelease?.TrySetResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can you use regular lock in awaitable code? Can't the same task continue as a different thread here and go around the lock?

Comment: @user1713059 note that `WaitAsync` isn't actually an `async` method. That means it doesn't yield control midway through processing. Instead, it obtains a `Task` from the `TaskCompletionSource` and returns it before releasing the lock.

Comment: Ah sure, so even if I do "await WaitAsync()" it is sure that the whole method gets executed by the same thread, because it's not actually async - is that right? The "Async" method suffix led me astray, but from what I see it's used in methods without the "async" keyword too.

Comment: It's still an asynchronous method because it returns a task which may not be completed by the time the method returns. However the method is not `async`, which means the method won't yield at some point within its body while it `await`s some other `Task`'s completion. It's convention for methods that return `Task` (or `Task<T>`) to have an `Async` suffix.

Comment: With respect to your original comment, the lock is released _before_ the `Task` is returned to the caller, so there's no way for that caller to get around the lock.

Answer (score 17):

I think there is good example on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#WHToTap

```
public static Task WaitOneAsync(this WaitHandle waitHandle)
{
    if (waitHandle == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("waitHandle");

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    var rwh = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(waitHandle, 
        delegate { tcs.TrySetResult(true); }, null, -1, true);
    var t = tcs.Task;
    t.ContinueWith( (antecedent) => rwh.Unregister(null));
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Definitely the best answer.

Comment: Note that this only works correctly on ManualResetEvent not AutoResetEvent. On AutoResetEvent you need to WaitOne the thing inside the delegate; else the event is still signalled next time somebody calls WaitOne on it.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a version I cooked up which allows you to specify a timeout. It is derived from Stephen Toub's solution. We currently use this in production workloads.

```
public class AsyncAutoResetEvent
{
    readonly LinkedList<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> waiters = 
        new LinkedList<TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();

    bool isSignaled;

    public AsyncAutoResetEvent(bool signaled)
    {
        this.isSignaled = signaled;
    }

    public Task<bool> WaitAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        return this.WaitAsync(timeout, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public async Task<bool> WaitAsync(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs;

        lock (this.waiters)
        {
            if (this.isSignaled)
            {
                this.isSignaled = false;
                return true;
            }
            else if (timeout == TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                return this.isSignaled;
            }
            else
            {
                tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                this.waiters.AddLast(tcs);
            }
        }

        Task winner = await Task.WhenAny(tcs.Task, Task.Delay(timeout, cancellationToken));
        if (winner == tcs.Task)
        {
            // The task was signaled.
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // We timed-out; remove our reference to the task.
            // This is an O(n) operation since waiters is a LinkedList<T>.
            lock (this.waiters)
            {
                bool removed = this.waiters.Remove(tcs);
                Debug.Assert(removed);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Set()
    {
        lock (this.waiters)
        {
            if (this.waiters.Count > 0)
            {
                // Signal the first task in the waiters list. This must be done on a new
                // thread to avoid stack-dives and situations where we try to complete the
                // same result multiple times.
                TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = this.waiters.First.Value;
                Task.Run(() => tcs.SetResult(true));
                this.waiters.RemoveFirst();
            }
            else if (!this.isSignaled)
            {
                // No tasks are pending
                this.isSignaled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Signaled: {this.isSignaled.ToString()}, Waiters: {this.waiters.Count.ToString()}";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this.waiters should be lock'ed at the in the Remove(tcs) manipulation path?

Comment: @HelloSam I think you are right! Fixed. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I don't have a lot of time to debug this, but, be forewarned: i am getting dead-lock using this. When a new thread calls event.Set(), it hangs on `toRelease.SetResult(true);`

Comment: @Andy thanks for the comment. There is an additional fix I made since I originally posted this which I suspect addresses your deadlock (in my case, it was a StackOverflowException). The fix was to wrap the `SetResult(true)` call in a `Task.Run(...)`.

Comment: Am I mistaken or is it not auto-resetting where it returns true after `if (winner == tcs.Task)`?

Comment: Never mind, I didn't understand how it works.  Turns out if there are tasks waiting it never bothers setting `isSignaled`

Answer (score 5):

I was also looking for an AsyncAutoResetEvent class and it seems there is now one available in namespace Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading

```
// Summary:
//     An asynchronous implementation of an AutoResetEvent.
[DebuggerDisplay("Signaled: {signaled}")]
public class AsyncAutoResetEvent
```

Comment: Here it is:
https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/AsyncAutoResetEvent.cs

Answer (score 3):

Install the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading` package (i did it using Nuget), then you will be able to use the `AsyncAutoResetEvent` class, which by its own documentation states:

> An asynchronous implementation of an AutoResetEvent.

docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asyncautoresetevent

Answer (score 2):

It also works, but this way may fade the purpose of using `async` and `await`.

```
AutoResetEvent asyncSignal = new AutoResetEvent();

async void Task1Proc()
{
    //do some stuff
    //..
    //..

    await Task.Run(() => asyncSignal.WaitOne()); //wait for an outer thread to signal we are good to continue

    //do some more stuff
    //..
    //..
}
```

Comment: Why is this considered bad?

Comment: @YarekT 
I remembered the reason at the time I wrote this answer months ago, but not now. I don't think this is bad, though there are more than one context switching (by WaitOne() and by await keyword) performance issue in this.

Comment: No worries. I've been recently looking more into Tasks in C#. From what I can gather its bad because it wastes a thread by creating one, then immediately making it blocked by the wait. I've seen a a few solutions floating around that avoid this by somehow using a timer, but they all seem very complicated. Anyway, heres an upvote

Comment: The issue with this approach is that it still blocks a thread. It doesn't block the one you're running on, it blocks another. If this only happens occasionally then maybe that's fine. But if you're handling larger workloads, you need twice as many thread pool threads for the same amount of work, even if half of them are asleep all the time.

Answer (score 2):

This could be much simpler implementation with SemaphoreSlim, I haven't tested this in production yet but it should work fine.

```
public class AsyncAutoResetEvent : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _waiters;

    public AsyncAutoResetEvent(bool initialState)
        => _waiters = new SemaphoreSlim(initialState ? 1 : 0, 1);

    public Task<bool> WaitOneAsync(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        => _waiters.WaitAsync(timeout, cancellationToken);

    public Task WaitOneAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        => _waiters.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);

    public void Set()
    {
        lock (_waiters)
        {
            if (_waiters.CurrentCount == 0)
                _waiters.Release();
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
        => $"Signaled: {_waiters.CurrentCount != 0}"; 

    private bool _disposed;
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _waiters.Dispose();
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have add this in Flettu Lib (just back lib for such tasks): https://github.com/mysteryjeans/Flettu/blob/master/src/Flettu/Lock/AsyncAutoResetEvent.cs

Answer (score 0):

I extended the example from MSDN provided by Oleg Gordeev with an optional Timeout (ms):

```
public static Task WaitOneAsync(this WaitHandle waitHandle, double timeout = 0)
        {
            if (waitHandle == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("waitHandle");

            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            if (timeout > 0) 
            {
                var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(timeout) 
                { Enabled = true, AutoReset = false };

                ElapsedEventHandler del = default;
                del = delegate (object x, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs y)
                {
                    tcs.TrySetResult(true);
                    timer.Elapsed -= del; 
                    timer.Dispose();
                };

                timer.Elapsed += del;
            }
        
            var rwh = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(waitHandle,
                      delegate { tcs.TrySetResult(true); },
                      null, -1, true);

            var t = tcs.Task;
            t.ContinueWith((antecedent) => rwh.Unregister(null));

            return t;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AsyncAutoResetEvent` with support of timed await. Notice the use of linked cancellation token source, which could cause some overhead for when disposing the created token source.

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading;

public static class AutoResetEventAsyncExtenstion
{
    
    public static async Task WaitAsync(this AsyncAutoResetEvent autoResetEvent, TimeSpan delay, CancellationToken stoppingToken= default)
    {
        using var timedCancellation = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(stoppingToken);
        timedCancellation.CancelAfter(delay);
        await autoResetEvent.WaitAsync(timedCancellation.Token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my version of one-time event can be await by multiple threads. It internally relies on `BoundedChannel`.

```
public class AsyncOneTimeEvent<T>
{
    private T Result { get; set; }

    private readonly Channel<bool> _channel = Channel.CreateBounded<bool>(new BoundedChannelOptions(1)
    {
        SingleReader = false,
        SingleWriter = true,
        FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.DropWrite,
    });

    public async Task<T> GetResult()
    {
        await _channel.Reader.WaitToReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        return this.Result;
    }

    public void SetResult(T result)
    {
        this.Result = result;
        _channel.Writer.Complete();
    }

    public void SetError(Exception ex)
    {
        _channel.Writer.Complete(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a `Channel` as a substitute of a `TaskCompletionSource` seems like a clever idea. But is also unnecessary, and the implementation seems susceptible to visibility problems. I am not sure that all threads will "see" the latest value of the non-volatile `private T Result` field in all cases.

Comment: Example: Thread A enters the `GetResult()` method, reads the value of `Result` in an out-of-order fashion, and then gets suspended by the OS. Thread B enters and exits the `SetResult` method. Thread A resumes, executes synchronously the `await _channel.Reader.WaitToReadAsync()` line, and returns a `Task` having `default(T)` as its value. Is this scenario impossible based on the C# ECMA-334 specification? I have no idea!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias certainly it works, you can try it online : https://dotnetfiddle.net/uyQRG1

Comment: I am sure that it works. I am not sure that it is guaranteed to work correctly on all CPU architectures. Visibility problems are notoriously difficult to debug. You can read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/december/csharp-the-csharp-memory-model-in-theory-and-practice) by Igor Ostrovsky to get an idea why.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my COMPLETE implementation using `SemaphoreSlim`, using all `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` overrides:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

/// <summary>
/// Represents an event that, when signaled, resets automatically after releasing a single waiting task.
/// </summary>
public sealed class AutoResetEventAsync : IDisposable {

    /// <summary>
    /// Waits asynchronously until a signal is received.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Task completed when the event is signaled.</returns>
    public async ValueTask WaitAsync() {
        if (CheckSignaled()) return;
        SemaphoreSlim s;
        lock (Q) Q.Enqueue(s = new(0, 1));
        await s.WaitAsync();
        lock (Q) if (Q.Count > 0 && Q.Peek() == s) Q.Dequeue().Dispose();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Waits asynchronously until a signal is received or the time runs out.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="millisecondsTimeout">The number of milliseconds to wait, <see cref="System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite"/>
    /// (-1) to wait indefinitely, or zero to return immediately.</param>
    /// <returns>Task completed when the event is signaled or the time runs out.</returns>
    public async ValueTask WaitAsync(int millisecondsTimeout) {
        if (CheckSignaled()) return;
        SemaphoreSlim s;
        lock (Q) Q.Enqueue(s = new(0, 1));
        await s.WaitAsync(millisecondsTimeout);
        lock (Q) if (Q.Count > 0 && Q.Peek() == s) Q.Dequeue().Dispose();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Waits asynchronously until a signal is received, the time runs out or the token is cancelled.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="millisecondsTimeout">The number of milliseconds to wait, <see cref="System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite"/>
    /// (-1) to wait indefinitely, or zero to return immediately.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The <see cref="System.Threading.CancellationToken"/> to observe.</param>
    /// <returns>Task completed when the event is signaled, the time runs out or the token is cancelled.</returns>
    public async ValueTask WaitAsync(int millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        if (CheckSignaled()) return;
        SemaphoreSlim s;
        lock (Q) Q.Enqueue(s = new(0, 1));
        try {
            await s.WaitAsync(millisecondsTimeout, cancellationToken);
        }
        finally {
            lock (Q) if (Q.Count > 0 && Q.Peek() == s) Q.Dequeue().Dispose();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Waits asynchronously until a signal is received or the token is cancelled.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The <see cref="System.Threading.CancellationToken"/> to observe.</param>
    /// <returns>Task completed when the event is signaled or the token is cancelled.</returns>
    public async ValueTask WaitAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        if (CheckSignaled()) return;
        SemaphoreSlim s;
        lock (Q) Q.Enqueue(s = new(0, 1));
        try {
            await s.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        finally {
            lock (Q) if (Q.Count > 0 && Q.Peek() == s) Q.Dequeue().Dispose();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Waits asynchronously until a signal is received or the time runs out.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeout">A <see cref="System.TimeSpan"/> that represents the number of milliseconds to wait,
    /// a <see cref="System.TimeSpan"/> that represents -1 milliseconds to wait indefinitely, or a System.TimeSpan
    /// that represents 0 milliseconds to return immediately.</param>
    /// <returns>Task completed when the event is signaled or the time runs out.</returns>
    public async ValueTask WaitAsync(TimeSpan timeout) {
        if (CheckSignaled()) return;
        SemaphoreSlim s;
        lock (Q) Q.Enqueue(s = new(0, 1));
        await s.WaitAsync(timeout);
        lock (Q) if (Q.Count > 0 && Q.Peek() == s) Q.Dequeue().Dispose();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Waits asynchronously until a signal is received, the time runs out or the token is cancelled.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeout">A <see cref="System.TimeSpan"/> that represents the number of milliseconds to wait,
    /// a <see cref="System.TimeSpan"/> that represents -1 milliseconds to wait indefinitely, or a System.TimeSpan
    /// that represents 0 milliseconds to return immediately.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The <see cref="System.Threading.CancellationToken"/> to observe.</param>
    /// <returns>Task completed when the event is signaled, the time runs out or the token is cancelled.</returns>
    public async ValueTask WaitAsync(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        if (CheckSignaled()) return;
        SemaphoreSlim s;
        lock (Q) Q.Enqueue(s = new(0, 1));
        try {
            await s.WaitAsync(timeout, cancellationToken);
        }
        finally {
            lock (Q) if (Q.Count > 0 && Q.Peek() == s) Q.Dequeue().Dispose();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the state of the event to signaled, allowing one or more waiting tasks to proceed.
    /// </summary>
    public void Set() {
        SemaphoreSlim? toRelease = null;
        lock (Q) {
            if (Q.Count > 0) toRelease = Q.Dequeue();
            else if (!IsSignaled) IsSignaled = true;
        }
        toRelease?.Release();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the state of the event to non nonsignaled, making the waiting tasks to wait.
    /// </summary>
    public void Reset() => IsSignaled = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes any semaphores left in the queue.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose() {
        lock (Q) {
            while (Q.Count > 0) Q.Dequeue().Dispose();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks the <see cref="IsSignaled"/> state and resets it when it's signaled.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if the event was in signaled state.</returns>
    private bool CheckSignaled() {
        lock (Q) {
            if (IsSignaled) {
                IsSignaled = false;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    private readonly Queue<SemaphoreSlim> Q = new();
    private volatile bool IsSignaled;

}
```

I used `SemaphoreSlim` because it gives the time out and cancellation token support "for free". It could be even better if I just modified the original .NET source code of `SemaphoreSlim` to behave like `AutoResetEvent` but nah, that's it. Let me know if you find any bugs.

Comment: Is the `AutoResetEventAsync` class thread-safe? If yes, what can happen if two threads call `WaitAsync()` at the same time? Isn't it possible that both will read the `IsSignaled` field as `true`, before any of them executes the `IsSignaled = false;` line? Also the `if (Q.Contains(s)) Q.Dequeue().Dispose();` line searches if the `s` exists in the queue, and then dequeues and disposes some other semaphore (most likely). Is this intentional?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias : Yes, because even if 2 threads can enter `WaitAsync` at the same time, they cannot pass the `Q` access at the same time. Notice that `Q` can be only accessed with a single thread. That makes the flow simple and direct. This also implies the internal await is accessible to a single thread only. Thus, it is impossible invalid semaphore is dequeued. The multiple tests I performed on this class haven't yet fail, but this doesn't prove it's valid. I think that the single tread access to Q does.

Comment: I am talking about this line: `if (IsSignaled) { IsSignaled = false; return; }`. This is not protected by a lock. The `IsSignaled` is not even a [`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile) field. As for the `if (Q.Contains(s))`, if you are sure that the `s` can only be in the head of the queue, `if (Q.Peak() == s)` would be faster and more expressive regarding the intentions of the code. Btw what will happen if the `cancellationToken` is canceled and the `WaitAsync` throws?

Comment: You've found some interesting edge cases. I'll try to fix them and edit my example... BRB.

Comment: Fixed. I had to add `if (Q.Count > 0)` because `Peek()` throws when Q is empty, and it is empty in most common case the `Set()` is invoked.

Comment: Your implementation transitioned from certainly flawed to potentially correct. But after closer inspection one race condition still exists (and maybe more). Assuming an initial state `IsSignaled = false`, one thread invokes the `WaitAsync` and another invokes the `Set`. The expected behavior after both invocations is that the first thread will **not** be in a waiting state. Alas your implementation allows this to happen, in case the `Set` is invoked by the second thread just after the first thread has executed the `CheckSignaled()`, and just before executing the `Q.Enqueue(s = new(0, 1))`.

Comment: Btw I am not sure what the `Reset` method is supposed to do, but mutating a non-volatile field without synchronization opens the can of worms that is called [memory models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/december/csharp-the-csharp-memory-model-in-theory-and-practice). Are you [an expert in coherency protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66490395/11178549), and can guarantee that this is not a problem? If not, then neither am I, and so there is no chance that I would use your class (as is) in a production environment.

Comment: The `Reset` seems to be redundant here, so it goes. About the race condition - I give up. `WaitAsync` can't block `Set()`. So how could I possibly prevent that particular condition from happening? BTW, that would happen only if I invoke `Set()` parallelly with `WaitAsync()` that would be just asking for a race condition. In my code I use this class to proceed when I/O operation completes. This event is used for one client session, so this will never happen. The I/O operation will never be completed before `WaitAsync()` enters `Enqueue()` part. Even if it throws.

Comment: Harry since you realize that implementing a custom asynchronous `AutoResetEvent` is challenging, why are you trying to roll your own, and don't just use Stephen Cleary's [`AsyncAutoResetEvent`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncAutoResetEvent)?

Comment: BTW, this class is not intended to be used to synchronize threads. Mixing manual thread synchronization with async pattern is not a good idea, because I think it's just extremely difficult to do correctly. That's probably why there is no `WaitAsync()` method in `AutoResetEvent` class in the first place.

Comment: Why? Because I needed a version that supports timeout and `CancellationToken`. I just needed it for my code, I use it and I just thought I could share it.

Comment: Hmm, Stephen Cleary's `AsyncAutoResetEvent` supports `CancellationToken`s, so the timeout functionality can be built on top of that. I just posted [here](https://gist.github.com/theodorzoulias/cc7f38d5423eee9f238f349605fc400a) an extension method that supports timeout and `CancellationToken` (optionally). Btw when you have an asynchronous implementation, implementing the synchronous functionality is trivial. Just call the asynchronous with `.GetAwaiter.GetResult()`. It's not very efficient, but gets the job done.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I will use the better version with your extension then. Anyway, it was totally worth it as a learning experience. You're MVP.