# ReaderWriterLockSlim - System.Threading.LockRecursionException: 'Recursive write lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode.' What is the Logic Error?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core

What is the main difference of `ReaderWriterLockSlim` than regular `Lock`?

Since I am trying to achieve `async`, `await`, I can't use regular `Lock`

So I am trying to make it work with `ReaderWriterLockSlim`

However I am getting this error,

```
System.Threading.LockRecursionException: 'Recursive write lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode.'
```

Isn't supposed `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to make queued threads/tasks to wait until released? So when the currently working thread on the given method is done, isn't the next in queued thread/task supposed to enter the method?

So lets say I have 5 tasks that wanted to access my method written as below and let's name them as A,B,C,D,E

Let's say B got the method and `_lockRootAdd` is now locked. Isn't A,C,D,E tasks supposed to wait until lock is released and once released aren't they supposed to enter the method 1 by 1?

```
private static readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _lockRootAdd = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    private static async Task<int> returnRootDomainId(this string srUrl)
    {
        _lockRootAdd.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            using ExampleCrawlerContext _context = new ExampleCrawlerContext();
            string rootDomain = srUrl.NormalizeUrl().returnRootDomainUrl();
            var rootDomainHash = rootDomain.SHA256Hash();

            var result = await _context.RootDomains.Where(pr => pr.RootDomainUrlHash == rootDomainHash).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (result == null)
            {
                RootDomains _RootDomain = new RootDomains();
                _RootDomain.RootDomainUrlHash = rootDomainHash;

                _context.Add(_RootDomain);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                await addUrl(rootDomain).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            var result2 = await _context.RootDomains.Where(pr => pr.RootDomainUrlHash == rootDomainHash).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            return result2.RootDomainId;
        }
        finally
        {
            _lockRootAdd.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the lock’s [RecursionPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.recursionpolicy?view=net-7.0) to [SupportsRecursion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.lockrecursionpolicy?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: The problem is that during the `await` inside the lock, the thread is allowed to do other work. One of the things it might be asked to do is `returnRootDomainId()`. If that happens, then you have a single thread acquiring the same slim lock twice, which is a lock recursion violation. In general, awaiting while holding a lock is a bad idea because it leads to problems like this. (Another common failure mode is a deadlock, where a thread is waiting to acquire a lock in read mode that it already owns in write mode.)

Comment: @stuartd that is what i want to prevent. I want only 1 thread to enter at a time

Comment: @RaymondChen i agree. but i am not calling returnRootDomainId inside returnRootDomainId twice. if i understand correctly, same thread is somehow calling returnRootDomainId twice. however if different threads call it, then this works. how can we prevent same thread entering inside it twice as well  and make them behave as different threads called it?

Comment: @RaymondChen so even if same threads calls it, calls should be queued like different threads called it. this is the behaviour when we use lock

Comment: Also, your ConfigureAwait(false) means that the await can resume on a different thread. This means that your final ExitWriteLock may not occur on the same thread as the EnterWriteLock, which is another lock violation. What you need is an [awaitable lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32654509/awaitable-autoresetevent).

Comment: @RaymondChen that came to my mind but ReaderWriterLockSlim  is a static object. so all threads using the same ReaderWriterLockSlim  object . therefore it shouldn't make difference?

Comment: `ReaderWriterLockSlim` isn't intended for use with async; see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19664437/2385218).  If all you're after is mutex in an async context, `SemaphoreSlim` is usually the go-to type.

Comment: @sellotape if i change code to SemaphoreSlim  should work directly or i would need other changes? gonna test now

Comment: Should work as-is.  Create it as `new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)` (the parameters logic is somewhat confusing).

Comment: @sellotape thank you looks like working much better :)

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, `ReaderWriterLockSlim` doesn't support `await`. The core problem is that traditional locks are thread-affine, and `await` can change threads.

The only out-of-the-box solution for `await`-compatible mutual exclusion is `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _lockRootAdd = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

private static async Task<int> returnRootDomainId(this string srUrl)
{
  await _lockRootAdd.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    ...
  }
  finally
  {
    _lockRootAdd.Release();
  }
}
```